# Redirect (port forwarding) from en0 to bridge0 (shared connection) on Mac 10.8.5

Tags: macos, sockets, routes, osx-mountain-lion

I want to communicate with my mobile app through sockets form a desktop Mac (app is server, desktop is client). I am using "Internet Sharing" to share connection from Ethernet to Wi-Fi. I am not allowed to use Wi-Fi by a wireless router which would make it easy to get both devices on the same LAN. My application works between the Mac and a diferent Windows PC on the same LAN. I can see that the server on the ported mobile app is working ok through traces.

However, when I try to connect to the mobile (assigned ip 192.68.2.2), it fails to connect.

Using "ifconfig"I see that the ethernet interfase is called "en0" and the wireless is "bridge0".

Is there a way to connect to "bridge0"? 
I read something about "natd" and "ssl" but couldn't make it work.

Furthermore, I would like to connect to the app from Windows to the app through the Desktop Mac.

Edit: I have seen that natd is deprecated on Mountain Lion (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5414) and pfctl has to be used. I am giving a try to that. Found this link for directions:
http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html

Edit2:
I have found a question that is similar to what I want to accomplish, but the other way (instead of getting the packets I want to send them). https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100492/redirect-traffic-using-pf-along-with-internet-sharing
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?